# Visual Studio 2022 is having issues with html tags in "if" blocks on Razor (chtml) pages

Tags: html, .net-core, razor, syntax, visual-studio-2022

When adding something like a div tag inside an if-block nested in div tag, Visual Studio will not finish the closing div tag. Worse yet, when I type "`</div>`" it will create another "`<div>`" in front of it.

The problem appears to be that it does not detect the opening div tag before the if-block and thinks the closing tag after the if-block is for that inner div. However, selecting the tags highlight the corresponding beginning or end tag.

Here is an example.

```
<div>
@if (condition)
{
    <div>
     THE FOLLOWING CLOSING TAG IS WHAT WILL NOT APPEAR.
    </div>          
}
</div>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What version of VS2022 are you using?  Some of these issues should have been addressed in 17.1. See https://github.com/dotnet/razor-compiler/issues/147#issuecomment-1097043345

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - LTSC 17.0
Version 17.0.10

Let me try your link.

Edit: TO be clear, I did do a "check for updates" but nothing returned. Ok, now checking your link.

Comment: I had to change my update channel to current. (I did not know it was set to LTSC 17.0)

I have updated to version 17.2.3. The bug is still there.

Comment: Have the same issue. on 17.2.6 (professional, windows 11 x64)

Answer (score 1):

A quick workaround I found is to first type the left-right angles `<>`, which automatically generates the corresponding `</>`.

Then, simply left-arrow into the `<>`, and type in `div`, or `span` etc - whatever you need.

Seems to work at multiple levels of nesting as well.